# which signal ProcessBuilder destroy method sends to the system?

Tags: java, shell, unix

I am running a shell script from java program and using `trap` command from the script to clean up before finish. But nothing worked so far.

Command and signals I used: `trap clean_up SIGSTOP SIGHUP SIGINT SIGTERM`

Looks like it is not `SIGKILL` because the shell script is still running after I call `process.destroy()`

Any suggestions?

Comment: I meant deploy method. sorry.

Comment: You can edit the question to fix the method name.

Comment: It will be necessary to provice the content of your script.